# С++ Как извлекать числа из файла в массив для дальнейшей манипуляции над этими числами . Есть допустим файл с числами

Tags: c++, visual-studio, файлы

Нужно срочно для ЕГЭ .
https://inf-ege.sdamgia.ru/problem?id=37348
Есть ли какие-то базовые функции для этой цели?
Без C-стайла ,пожалуйста и без векторов . С использованием библиотеки fstream .
Нужен просто легкий способ считать числа из файла в массив, а не решение этого задания

Comment: Ваша ссылка не открывается. Лучше приведите пример файла прямо в вопросе. И почему нельзя использовать вектора?

Comment: Метка c# лишняя походу?

Comment: Чего мучиться, решайте на Паскале.

Answer (score 0):

первая половина задачи - чтение

```
std::fstream f("файл");
int number;
while (f >> number) {
  // добавьте в массив
  vector.push_back(number);
}
```

но вот условие " Без C-стайла ,пожалуйста и без векторов . " взаимоисключающее. Потому что придется заводить динамический массив. А это либо malloc (чистой воды си), либо new + указатели (а это на самом деле тоже си стайл, хотя и не си).

Поэтому, используйте вектор, это хороший с++ стиль. Или покажите, как Вы видите динамический массив в с++ стиле и я допишу ответ.

Answer (score 0):

Хорошо бы знать, как в файле разделены числа. Если они разделены переходом на новую строку, то чтение строк можно глянуть тут [Как вывести строку файла под определенным номером?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1351450/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BC)

Считываемые строки переводим в тип int с помощью функции std::stoi(), которая принимает строку и возвращает int. Например:

```
int arr = new int[100];
arr[0] = std::stoi(str);
```

Если что-то не понятно, напишите.