# Как вывести строку файла под определенным номером?

Tags: c++, fstream

Мне нужно получить и вывести из текстового файла строку, номер который задается случайно. Сейчас есть такой код:

```
void chooseword() {
    string str;
    string wordtogame;
    int wordtotake;
    int stringnumber = 0;
    srand(time(0));
    ifstream read;
    read.open("WORDSLIST.txt");
    if (!(read.is_open)())
        cout << "Файл со словами не открыт\n";
    while (getline(read, str))
        stringnumber++;
    wordtotake = rand() % (stringnumber - 1 + 1) + 1;
    read.close();
}
```

Что сделать, чтобы строка под номером `wordtotake` записалась в переменную `wordtogame`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так. Единственное - стоит переработать способ перехода в начало файла.

```
void chooseword() {
string str;
string wordtogame;
int wordtotake;
int stringnumber = 0;
srand(time(0));
ifstream read;

read.open("WORDSLIST.txt");
if (!(read.is_open)())
    cout << "Файл со словами не открыт\n";
while (getline(read, str))
    stringnumber++;
wordtotake = rand() % (stringnumber) + 1;  //убрал лишнее (-1+1)

read.close();
read.open("WORDSLIST.txt"); //с помощью закрытия и повторного открытия файла ставим указатель в начало файла (есть другие способы, но быстро их прикрутить не получилось)

while (getline(read, str))
{
    if (wordtotake == 1)
    {
        int lenthstr = str.length();
        wordtogame = str.substr(0, lenthstr - 1);
        break;
    }
    --wordtotake;
}
cout << wordtogame;
read.close();
```

}

Цикл пробегает по строкам. Если рандом выбрал ранее первую строку, то условие для if выполняется сразу. Если строка имеет иной номер, то номер выбранной строки декрементируется, что позволяет циклу выполниться ещё раз с переходом на следующую строку, и так пока не получим требуемую строку.
Например:

- wordtotake равен 4
- считывается строка номер 1 до символа \n, условие для if не выполняется, wordtotake уменьшается до 3
- считывается строка номер 2 до символа \n, условие для if не выполняется, wordtotake уменьшается до 2
- считывается строка номер 3 до символа \n, условие для if не выполняется, wordtotake уменьшается до 1
- считывается строка номер 4 до символа \n, условие для if выполняется, полученная строка записывается в wordtogame, break завершает работу цикла while.

Функция substr() возвращает из строки символы от и до указанных в первом и втором аргументе, вспоминаем нумерацию индексов в массивах и указываем от нулевого (первого) символа до длинны полученной строки минус 1.

Примечание. Если номер выбранной строки (wordtotake) нужно сохранить без изменений до конца выполнения функции, то можно присвоить его другой переменной и декрементировать в цикле уже её.